# How to map nested objects as parameter for Spring roo MVC Controller

Tags: java, json, spring, model-view-controller, roo

I am trying to map a complex object which contains a list of complex objects.

But after mapping (no errors) the List of this complex objects is empty.

Probably I need to add an annotation or something else, any ideas or suggestions?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/newTrip", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Trip create(@Valid Trip trip,
                   BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        populateEditForm(uiModel, trip);
        return null;
    }

    if(trip.getWaypoints() == null || trip.getWaypoints().isEmpty()){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    return TripBL.createTrip(trip);
}
```